# Add OLEObjects work inside macro and fail if executed as vbs script in cmd

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

code executed inside the excel file (xlsm) work perfectly

```
 Sub insertObject()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("YourPath\Datasheet.xlsx")
    objExcel.Application.Visible = True
    objWorkbook.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="YourPath\Placeholder.txt", _
            Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
            "C:\Windows\system32\packager.dll", IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
            "C:\Placeholder.txt").Select
    objWorkbook.SaveAs "yourPath\test.xlsx"
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Application.Quit
    WScript.Quit
    End Sub
```

this is the code i try to execute using vbs script

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("YourPath\Datasheet.xlsx")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="YourPath\Placeholder.txt", _
        Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        "C:\Windows\system32\packager.dll", IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
        "C:\Placeholder.txt").Select
objWorkbook.SaveAs "YourPath\test.xlsx"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

i replace the paths with the real ones of course the code work perfectly inside the macro but failed  inside vbs script when i try to run it using the cmd command.

Comment: Failed in what way? What happended? Did you get error messages/codes?

Comment: the code is 800A03Ec , methode add of OLEObjects failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same thing when I run your code. I tried a few different tweaks  and it works:
you simply forgot the first parameter of the add function of OLEobject and dont forget to remove the parameters names :

```
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("YourPath\Datasheet.xlsx")
    objExcel.Application.Visible = false
    Set ob = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    Set t = ob.Add (,"YourPath\Placeholder.txt",False, True,    "C:\Windows\system32\packager.dll", 0,"C:\Placeholder.txt")
```